# Java operations on an array of integers

Tags: java, arrays, boolean, xor, nim-game

I'm considering an array of integers in Java. The array size is determined at the start of the program by the user

My idea idea is that - given any position for the corresponding binary values - the result should show 1 for any bit where only one of the operands has a 1 and 0 for any other combination. The process can be better explained by the following examples

An array such {4,5,6} should return 3 because:

```
  100
  101
  110
  ---
= 011
```

OR for the numbers {12,4,9}

```
12 = 1100
 4 = 0100
 9 = 1001
---------
Val- 0001
```

I thought of doing it this way but I realized that - since I worked with XOR - my code for the first example will return 7 :

```
static void cpuTurn(int[] nimArray){
    int[] val = new int[nimArray.length];
    int holding = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nimArray.length; i++) {
        holding = holding^nimArray[i];
    }
}
```

How to implement this operation correctly?

Comment: I believe 7 is the correct answer.  Why do you think it's 3?

Comment: `100` ^ `101` is `001`.  `001` ^ `110` is `111`, which is `7`.

Comment: Sorry i should have said, I'm trying to XOR all at once or get the corresponding value. I do realise that the output is correct here but just not in terms of what I want to do :)

Comment: Can you clear what you want because you are exactly XORing all values...

Comment: "I'm trying to XOR all at once" - Isn't that what you're doing already?

Comment: @EllisThompson my answer clearly shows that you are XORing all the three together. You should make us understand how you calculate the value 3 that you are expecting

Comment: I repeat my question.  Why do you think 3 is the right answer?  It's not clear to any of us what you mean by "XOR all at once".  Do you mean, you want a bit to be set in the result if it's set in _exactly one_ of the values being operated on?  If that's what you mean, then the answer will indeed be 3.  Please clarify if that is your intent.

Comment: Sorry again I've added more clarity, I want a singular output such that if there is more than exactly 1 1 (as if it were  a binary value) then the resultant output would be 0. I can solve it by converting all to binary and checking if each place is one and setting the output for the corresponding place to 0 if there is more than 1, 1 but for a large array this is impractical

Comment: @Antonino I'm hoping to XOR them concurrently as apposed to one after the other. with larger arrays the resultant value of holding will always tend to or result in all 1s (if converted to binary)

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I don't think 3 is the correct answer. logically i know it is but in terms of what I am aiming for it is not. I want in basic terms an XOR with multiple inputs

Comment: So you've changed your mind about what you want?

Comment: No, my explanation was admittedly vague and ambiguous and not useful do describe my true intentions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understand this way:

```
holding = 0
at 4:
holding = holding ^ 4; // 0 ^ 4 = 4 i.e. holding = 4, binary => 0 ^ 100 = 100  
at 5:
holding = holding ^ 5; // 4 ^ 5 = 1 i.e. holding = 1, binary => 100 ^ 101 = 1 
at 6:
holding = holding ^ 6; // 1 ^ 6 = 7 i.e. holding = 7, binary => 1 ^ 110 = 111
```

Thus final value of holding is 7.

If you want to set more than two 1 appearances to 0

```
    public static int[] split(int num){
        int[] splits = new int[31]; 
        for(int i=0; i < 31; ++i){
            splits[i] = (num>>i & 1);
        }
        return splits;
    }

    static void cpuTurn(int[] nimArray){
        int[] val = new int[nimArray.length];
        int holding = 0;
        int [] holdings = split(holding);
        for (int i = 0; i < nimArray.length; i++) {
            int [] splits = split(nimArray[i]);
            for(int j = 0; j < splits.length; ++j)
                 holdings[j]+=splits[j]
        }

        int [] newVal = new int[31];
        int k =0;
        for(k = 0; k < 31; ++k)
            if(holdings[k]>1 || holdings[k]==0)
                newVal[k] = 0;
            else
                newVal[k] = 1;

        int finalValue = 0;
        for(k = 0; k < 31; ++k)
             finalValue |= newVal[k]<<k;

        System.out.println(finalValue);

    }
```

Comment: Yeah sorry, I understand that its logically correct but in terms of what I'm aiming to do its not 'correct'. I have added clarity to my post now though :) Thanks anyway

Comment: @EllisThompson: made some edits ... is that what you want exactly..?

Comment: Yes thanks! This helps a lot and is simpler than what I started to work on!

Answer (score 2):

There might be a smarter way, but you can solve it iteratively by selecting bits that are only present once in your array and OR'ing them together. Here's a way to do that with streams:

```
IntStream.range(0, 32)
        .map(i -> 1 << i)
        .filter(i -> Arrays.stream(array).filter(n -> (n & i) != 0).count() == 1)
        .reduce(0, (a, b) -> a | b)
```

[**Ideone Demo**](https://ideone.com/BcyyU1)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this fairly simply by keeping track of which bits are not unique.

```
static int xor(int[] arr) {
    int all = 0;
    int dup = 0;

    for (int x : arr) {
        // for each x in arr, record the bits which are
        // in common with the bits we've already seen
        dup |= x & all;
        all |= x;
    }

    // remove bits which were not unique
    return all & ~dup;
}
```

Thinking about how this works, you could say that the variable `all` keeps a counter for each bit, but we can only count to 1. When we do `x & all` we get a 1 for each bit we've seen at least once *plus* once more in `x`, effectively letting us count to 2. `dup` then keeps track of each bit that we see more than once.

At the end we just do `all & ~dup` which removes any of the bits that we saw more than once.